# Invite facebook friends to private website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got question about using Facebook API. I've concept what would i like to do, but I'm not sure it's possible.

So:
1. User creates (using facebook connect) account on my website
2. User creates some kind of private journal
3. User invites his/hers Facebook friends to his/hers private journal
4. Any invited friend after signin-in (using FB connect) can view all private journals to which was invited to

Extra: later user can manage list of his friends that have access to his private journal (give/take access)

Is that possible and how?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite The rest around it (let people see specific journals only), you will have to implement yourself.

Comment: thanks, can I save some id's, name, profile pictures of peoples who recieves message? So i can validate later, after their signin in, if they have permissions and manage that list?